# How to split a string variable in powershell and rename a folder

Tags: powershell

does anybody know how to split a string variable in Powershell and rename the file by adding a number and file extension?

My scenario and example of variables I'm using:

$return_path = "C:\FolderA\result.txt"

How do I get the "C:\FolderA\result" portion? I have tried Split-Path but I keep getting this error below. Even though there is indeed a value in $return_path but it still says that it is null
[Error splitting File Path](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sjHaV.png)

Also I am trying to loop through a dataset and I need to append "i" to the retrieved file name after I split it, for example, "C:\FolderA\result[i].txt", but currently, my code below is outputting an error which is attached at Screenshot 3 below. Is the error because I cannot check if an integer is less than number of data set returned? Any answers would be appreciated as I need help after trying and researching but I am still stuck. Thank you.

[Looping through retrieved tables from dataset (Count how many tables returned)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mGZYV.png)

[Error comparing in loop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0mVDF.png)

Comment: Please update your question with the code and errors in plain text, properly formatted.

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages (as applicable) as _text_, [not (just) as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Answer (score 0):

For your ask, Try this :

```
$return_path = "C:\FolderA\result.txt"

#get file name extension
$FileExtension=[System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($return_path)

#get file name without extension
$FileNameWithoutExtension=[System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($return_path)

#get directory path
$Directory=[System.IO.Path]::GetDirectoryName($return_path)

for ($i = 1; $i -lt $ds.Tables.Count; $i++)
{

#build file name 
$PathFile=[System.IO.Path]::Combine($Directory, $FileNameWithoutExtension + $i + $FileExtension)

#export current table
$ds.Tables[$i] | export-csv $PathFile -Delimiter '|' -notypeinformation    
}
```

But ideally your should do it :

```
$initdir = "C:\FolderA\" # define your inital directory
$FileName="result" # define your final file name
$Extension=".CSV"  #use csv and not txt extension for csv file

for ($i = 1; $i -lt $ds.Tables.Count; $i++)
{

#build file name 
$PathFile=[System.IO.Path]::Combine($initdir, $FileName + $i + $Extension)

#export current table
$ds.Tables[$i] | export-csv $PathFile -Delimiter '|' -notypeinformation    
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I am currently editing my code now with your code. But do you know if it's possible to use $FileExtension = ".txt" instead as the file I am currently retrieving is actually a PowerShell file extension. And have it appended to $PathFile without any errors? I am having another error which prevents me from outputting your code and checking if it can successfully run.

Comment: Yes you can use .txt if you want. Yes my code work with powershell 5 minimum